# Generating the large number of samples in r

Tags: r, sampling

*I have a data frame of 50 rows and 4 columns. I want to get many sample data frames of 12 rows May be a million of them and i do not want my two sample data frames to be same. I have used the following code*

```
    df_l <- list()
    for(i in 1:6000000) {
    set.seed(100+i)
    a <- df[sample(nrow(df),12,replace=T),]
    df_l[[i]] <- a
   rownames(df_l[[i]]) <- 1:12 
   }
```

*But my confusion is this might not be the efficient way to do it and i do not know if two of the sample data-frame are same or not.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below:

- without replacement when sampling

```
n <- nrow(df)
df_1 <- replicate(6000000,df[sample(n,12),],simplify = FALSE)
```

- with replacement when sampling

```
n <- nrow(df)
df_1 <- replicate(6000000,df[sample(n,12,replace = TRUE),],simplify = FALSE)
```

---

Regarding the concern of the same data frames, it depends on the size of space that you are sampling from. For your case,

- if you don't allow replacement, your space size is `choose(50,12)*factorial(12)`, which is much larger than `6000000`. Thus, the probability of collision is low.
- if you allow replacement, your space size is `50**12*factorial(12)`, which is even larger than the scenario without replacement. Thus, the probability of collision would be much lower.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is not very efficient.

1) you need to set the seed only once.

2) R is an interpreted language, and it is very slow when using basic branching functions  (e.g., if, for, while ...) or variable operations (e.g., a <- a+1). The interpreting costs time in particular for functions that only take a short time.
So, you want to call a function that does a lot at once, because when stated, it is fast as it is likely implemented in a much faster way (they are usually compiled).

By just swapping the 1:6000000 with 1:12 and taking a sample vector of 6000000, this will make your program run much faster. You just need to arrange how you arrange the data.

3) try [replicate](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/06/05/a-closer-look-at-replicate-and-purrr/)

Answer (score 3):

The approach that you're trying is rather slow for a couple of reasons (outlined below), and it also involves a lot of data duplication, which isn't usually efficient.

First, you're using a loop to perform your sampling, which is often slow in R.  It's almost always better to try to 'vectorize' your calculations, meaning to try to do them all with the same base R command.  In this case, we can do the row sampling for all of your subsamples at the same time, and then allocate the sampled rows to each subsample afterwards.

Secondly, you're creating a list - `df_l` which contains a large number of repeats of your original `df` data.  This is wasteful (you don't need to potentially store the same data multiple times), and takes a lot of work to do.  It's again almost always better to just use indices to access the original data.

So, putting this together, we can create a faster approach that also doesn't duplicate the data:

First, some test data:

```
df=data.frame(matrix(sample(1:200),ncol=4))
```

Now, instead of replicating the data in a list of a lot of new dataframes, we just create a matrix of sampled indices:

```
make_index_samples=function(df,n) {
    return(matrix(sample(nrow(df),12*n,replace=T),nrow=n))
}
random_indices=make_index_samples(df,1000)
```

So, now, instead of accessing the randomly-sampled df `n` using `df_l[[n]]` (as in the original example), we just use:

```
my_random_df=df[random_indices[n,],]
```

We can use `microbenchmark` to see how much faster this is:

```
# (almost) original sampling
make_samples_original=function(df,n) {
    df_l=list()
    set.seed(123)
    for(i in seq_len(n)) {
        df_l[[i]]=df[sample(nrow(df),12,replace=T),]
    }
    return(df_l)
}

# compare making list of new dfs to making matrix of indices:
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(make_samples_original(df,1000),make_index_samples(df,1000))
# Unit: microseconds
#                             expr        min          lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
#  make_samples_original(df, 1000) 103515.198 111525.9985 116499.0323 115045.9485 118883.329 200982.370   100
#     make_index_samples(df, 1000)    234.193    246.0805    307.6667    249.3815    300.382    755.873   100
```

So sampling the indices is about 300x faster.

Now, regarding 'repeated' identical samples: as pointed out by @ThomasIsCoding, the number of exactly-identical samples of 12 is very big (2e20) so you're unlikely to get any perfect 'collisions'.
However, if you consider 'the same' to also include two samples with the same set of rows, but in a different order, then there are *only* `50^12/factorial(12)` combinations, or 5e11.  This may seem a lot, but the 'birthday paradox' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) shows that you *only* need to sample about 7e5 times to be likely to have at least one 'collision'.

So with 1 million randomizations, you're likely to have one or two samples with the same set of rows.  For many applications, this isn't likely to be a big problem.  If it is for you, you could check each randomization to be sure that it hasn't occurred previously, but this might undo most or all of the benefit faster sampling...

Anyway, here's one way to do it:

First, we make a few more randomized samples than we actually want, so that we can discard any duplicates and still have enough:

```
set.seed(123)
random_indices=make_index_samples(df,1000100) # 1 million +100 extra
```

Then, we construct a name for each randomized sample that uniquely identifies the sampled rows inside it, but (in this case) without worrying about the order of the rows:

```
random_index_names=apply(random_indices,1,function(row) paste(sort(row),collapse="_"))
```

We can check if there were any collisions (which will be revealed by duplicated names), and discard these:

```
sum(duplicated(random_index_names)) # I got 1 duplicate!  
random_indices.no_duplicates=random_indices[-duplicated(random_index_names),][1:1000000,]
```